# What is the completion of $L^\infty$ in the dual of BV?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Every $f \in L^\infty([0,1])$ induces a continuous linear functional on BV via $g \mapsto \int f g   \mathrm{d}x$. I believe $L^\infty([0,1])$ is also separable in BV$^\ast$, while BV$^\ast$ is not separable, so it cannot be the case the BV$^\ast$ completion of $L^\infty([0,1])$ is all of BV$^\ast$.

Is there a nice characterization of the BV$^\ast$ completion of $L^\infty([0,1])$?

Comment: I have not thought through the details, but have you tried integrating by parts, since IIRC g is in BV if and only if it is an indefinite integral of a (Borel) measure on [0,1]?